# Eclipse Plugin Development :How to make custom eclipse project to run on Server?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, project, launch

I am developing some eclipse plugins which requires to run,debug custom eclipse project on server like any other dynamic web project.

Like dynamic web project in eclipse i have created a custom project nature of web project & i want to deploy and run project on server like tomcat using Run On Server wizard of eclipse.So basically i want to know how to create IModuleArtifact object from custom project and deploy it using server wizard of eclipse.

Can somebody guide me in right direction??
Thanks.

Comment: What kind of plugins? What kind of projects? What kind of server?

Comment: Like dynamic web project in eclipse i have created a custom project nature of web project & i want to deploy and run project on server like tomcat using Run On Server wizard of eclipse.So basically i want to know how to create IModuleArtifact object from custom project and deploy it using server wizard of eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far i can understand you have a web project but structure different to dynamic web project.
So you can add web project nature to the project using following-

```
 IFacetedProject facetedProject = ProjectFacetsManager.create(project, true, null);
 IFacetedProjectWorkingCopy workingCopy = facetedProject.createWorkingCopy();
 IProjectFacet webFacet = ProjectFacetsManager.getProjectFacet("jst.web"); 
 IProjectFacetVersion defaultWebFacet = webFacet.getDefaultVersion();
 workingCopy.addProjectFacet(defaultWebFacet);
```

And then change the deployment settings using project ->properties->Deployment Assembly
to map project resources that will go into WAR file.
You can also configure this programatically using following code-

```
IVirtualComponent rootComponent = ComponentCore
                .createComponent(project);
IFolder buildXwtFolder =//Source Folder;
        IVirtualFolder rootFolder = rootComponent.getRootFolder();
        IVirtualFolder subFolder = rootFolder.getFolder("Deploy path");
        subFolder.createLink(buildXwtFolder.getProjectRelativePath(), 0,
                null);
        if (subFolder instanceof ITaggedVirtualResource) {
            ((ITaggedVirtualResource) subFolder).tagResource(
                    buildXwtFolder.getProjectRelativePath(),
                    null, null);
        }
```